# Ps1 Create Custom Attribute Script to Set-ADObject : 'The parameter is incorrect'/ A Referral was returned from the Server

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have a powershell script to create a set of Custom AD Attributes. It works on a local VM with win 2019. It does NOT work on a Win 2019 Server (created in AWS - EC2 image where 1 box is the main DC and the other box is a replicated AD). I was running this on the replicated server, not the main dc (maybe that's the problem?)
This is the script:

```
# Create a new Object Identifier (OID) using a test prefix. 
Function New-AttributeID {
    $Prefix = "1.2.840.113556.1.8000.2554"
    $GUID = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    $Parts = @()
    $Parts += [UInt64]::Parse($GUID.SubString(0, 4), "AllowHexSpecifier")
    $Parts += [UInt64]::Parse($GUID.SubString(4, 4), "AllowHexSpecifier")
    $Parts += [UInt64]::Parse($GUID.SubString(9, 4), "AllowHexSpecifier")
    $Parts += [UInt64]::Parse($GUID.SubString(14, 4), "AllowHexSpecifier")
    $Parts += [UInt64]::Parse($GUID.SubString(19, 4), "AllowHexSpecifier")
    $Parts += [UInt64]::Parse($GUID.SubString(24, 6), "AllowHexSpecifier")
    $Parts += [UInt64]::Parse($GUID.SubString(30, 6), "AllowHexSpecifier")
    $OID = [String]::Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}.{4}.{5}.{6}.{7}", $Prefix, $Parts[0], $Parts[1], $Parts[2], $Parts[3], $Parts[4], $Parts[5], $Parts[6])

    return $OID
}

# ...
#
# Create a new attribute and attach it to User Objects.
#
# PARAMETER $Name
#   The name of the attribute you are creating. This will be the CN and the LDAP Display Name. Using a standard prefix
#   is a good practice to follow.
#
# PARAMETER $LDAPDisplayName
#   The attribute's display name.
#
# PARAMETER $AdminDescription
#   A short description that is added as metadata to the attribute.
#
# PARAMETER [$AttributeID]
#   An optional Object Identifier (OID) to assign to the attribute. If omitted, a new OID is generated.
Function Update-Schema {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess, ConfirmImpact = 'High')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName)]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName)][Alias('DisplayName')]$LDAPDisplayName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName)][Alias('Description')]$AdminDescription,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName)][Alias('OID')]$AttributeID = (New-AttributeID)
    )

    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS {
      $schemaPath = (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext
      $type = 'attributeSchema'
      $attributes = @{
        lDAPDisplayName = $Name;
        attributeId = $AttributeID;
        oMSyntax = 4; # octet string
        attributeSyntax = "2.5.5.10";
        isSingleValued = $false;
        adminDescription = $AdminDescription;
      }

      $confirmationMessage = "$schemaPath. This cannot be undone"
      $caption = 'Updating Active Directory Schema'
      if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($confirmationMessage, $caption)) {
        # ...
        #
        # Create attribute.
        New-ADObject -Name $Name -Type $type -Path $schemapath -OtherAttributes $attributes

        # ...
        #
        # Attach attribute to User Object.
        $userSchema = Get-ADObject -SearchBase $schemaPath -Filter 'name -eq "user"'
        $userSchema | Set-ADObject -Add @{mayContain = $Name}
      }
    }

    END {}
}
```

When it iterates through for the first time to create the first attribute, I get this error:

```
New-ADObject : A referral was returned from the server
At C:\update_ad_schema_shared_ad_storage.ps1:77 char:9
+     New-ADObject -Name $Name -Type $type -Path $schemapath -Other ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo     : ResourceUnavailable: (cn=sc-custom1,C...<DomainNameHere>,DC=com:String) [New-ADObject], ADReferralException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8235,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADObject
Set-ADObject : The parameter is incorrect
At C:\update_ad_schema_shared_ad_storage.ps1:83 char:23
+     $userSchema | Set-ADObject -Add @{mayContain = $Name}
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo     : InvalidOperation: (CN=User,CN=Sche...<domainNameHere>,DC=com:ADObject) [Set-ADObject], ADInvalidOperationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:87,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADObject
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when the script was executed on a non-Primary DC. When run on a Primary Domain Controller (with FSMO) it ran w/o error!